# VB, I keep getting login failed for user... when I'm trying to connect to sql server database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I cannot connect to my local sql server using the following line

```
conn = SqlConnection("server=(local);uid=tedpottel;pwd=#######;database=by")
```

I have security set to Windows Authentication , so my other programs (reporting services and cold fusion do not take in a password. (as long as I log in as tedpottel) So I tried

```
conn = SqlConnection("server=(local);database=by")
```

which said "failed for user''"

Comment: Are you sure that you are authorized to access that server and database?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do windows authentication, you don't need userID and password

You need to add `;Trusted_Connection=True`, it would look like this

```
Server=(local);Database=by;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

see here http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

Comment: Hi,Thank you for taking the time to answer my quastion, I was really stuck

Comment: how about if i use windows authentication, but want to connect it from other pc on same network (VMWare for example)? @SQLMenace

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have Mixed Authentication enabled:

[image]

and are you sure that you are typing in the password correctly as well?